# AVAudioPlayer sounds stop playing after so many IBActions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have a simple interactive app with 10 IBActions, each linked to animations and sound.  After tapping multiple times the sounds stop working (although in the case of the music button it will keep playing but no other sounds will work but once it is turned off all sounds stop) but the animations and everything else runs fine.   It is a lot of taps... but after a few minutes of interaction ie. 50 or so taps this happens.

I see no leaks in instruments...  Everything looks fine, it just stops working?

Any ideas what could be happening?

I am using AVAudioPlayer framework   with code

```
AVAudioPlayer *bubblesound;

-(IBAction) getBubbles:(id)sender {

    NSString *bubblesgoblip = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"boingy1" ofType:@"mp3"];

    bubblesound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bubblesgoblip] error:NULL];

    [bubblesound play];  }             

-(void)dealloc {
  [bubblesound release];


}
```

Comment: You will have to post some code as there are different ways to play sounds in iOS.

Comment: I am using AVAudioPlayer framework

Answer (score 2):

Its weird you don't get leaks as you initiating bubblesound again and again.

Any way:

If you are paling short buttons sound effects you better try and use "***SystemSoundID***" and not AVAudioPlayer. thats what apple recommends.

**Etited**
apple has a great example that includes this file -

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>

@interface SoundEffect : NSObject {
    SystemSoundID _soundID;
}

+ (id)soundEffectWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath;
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path;
- (void)play;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "SoundEffect.h"

@implementation SoundEffect
+ (id)soundEffectWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath {
    if (aPath) {
        return [[[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:aPath] autorelease];
    }
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path {
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil) {
        NSURL *aFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];

        if (aFileURL != nil)  {
            SystemSoundID aSoundID;
            OSStatus error = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)aFileURL, &aSoundID);

            if (error == kAudioServicesNoError) { // success
                _soundID = aSoundID;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error %ld loading sound at path: %@", error, path);
                [self release], self = nil;
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"NSURL is nil for path: %@", path);
            [self release], self = nil;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(_soundID);
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)play {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_soundID);
}

@end
```

now you can prepare the sounds in your view did load -

```
   NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        sound1 = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"doorloop1" ofType:@"caf"]];
        sound2 = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[mainBundle pathForResource:@"doorloop1" ofType:@"caf"]];
```

And at last in your action

```
-(IBAction) getBubbles:(id)sender {
    [sound1 play];
}
```

Dont forget to release the sounds.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, as well as changing [self.bubblesound stop]; to [bubblesound release]; in the if statement, the app still eventually stops playing sound, same as before and still shows no leaks in instruments, Also this problem does not exist when it runs in simulator.  I will look into SystemSoundID, thanks for the info.

Comment: cool thanks, I will try this!  I haven't had the chance for a few days, but hopefully I can get this working today!

Comment: also, with my old problem, even though instruments showed no "leaks" my allocations keep growing every time I touch an action linked to sound until all sounds stop.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using. Do you "Prepare your sounds" in the view did load? or any time you click a button? post your code an i will try to help.

Comment: ugh, still working on this using the systemsoundID example above, but I have some errors to figure out, sorry the growing allocations comment pertained to the old avaudioplayer code I had been using.

Comment: It works but I have warnings of incompatible pointer type . In .h of myViewController I #import "SoundEffect.h" with under @interface myViewController SystemSoundID *sound1;  cool thing is I don't see my allocations growing like before.